# Rails, DRY default validator for string length?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

So I am having an issue where length errors are rails exception because the model doesn't have a length validation on it.

I understand I can put a length validator on my string by using

```
validates :blah, length: { maximum: 255 }
```

However most of my strings are using the default size of 255, so I would have to repeat this validation in a lot of places.

**Is there a DRY way to put a default validator on all strings to validate to the default database length of 255?**

Comment: Would it help to have a way to have `validates` assume a `length: { maximum: 255 }` default?

Comment: If so, see answer just posted. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably isn't exactly the answer you are looking for but if you add multiple fields to the validator then you aren't really repeating the validator and seems fairly DRY to me.

```
validates :foo, :bar, :baz, length: { maximum: 255 }
```

Comment: That is good for fields in a single model, but not across all models. That is still better then have a validator per line.

Comment: This is what I ended up going with, sad that there isn't a DRYer way to do this, but this is fine for now.

Answer (score 6):

The gem **schema_validations** (https://github.com/SchemaPlus/schema_validations) does what you want.

> Automatically creates validations basing on the database schema.
>
> It inspect the database and automatically creates validations basing on the schema. After installing it your model is as simple as it can be.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

> Validations are there but they are created by schema_validations under the hood.

Comment: That gem doesn't appear to actual validate field maximums, unless you manually specify `:limit`.

Comment: After added this gem, you need to restart your application, otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ModelName < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, length: { maximum: 255 }
end
```

Then use it by typing

```
ModelName.validators
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are getting at here, could you provide more information?